# triangles with angle of $60$ degrees and $120$ degrees

Tags: geometry, math-history

I have made some research and did not find this topic already, sorry if this has already been discussed somewhere.

The case of triangles with an angle of $60$ degree is special since there is a relation on sides which is quite close to the Pythagorean equality ($c^2=a^2+b^2-ab$), and there is also a formula for triangles with an angle of $120$ degrees. This is trivial using trigonometry and remains quite easy without it, using similar triangles and a few tricks. So my question is : it is known when was this result studied/written for the first time and was it long before the study of trigonometry? Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Aside: These are special cases of the law of cosines; it becomes simple when the cosine is $0$ (right triangle) or $\pm 1/2$ (60 and 120 degrees).

Comment: I suggest you ask at [HSM SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), which is an SE site specifically for questions about the history of science and mathematics.